# How to chose values for QC for a GWAS?

Tags: gwas, qc, maf

I am running a GWAS on a large dataset. I am using the H3aBioNet QC workflow (https://github.com/h3abionet/h3agwas/blob/master/qc/README.md).

I have run the QC on initial parameters:

1. MAF < 0.01
2. GENO > 0.05
3. HWE 0.0000001

My question is now that I have the output, do I need to change these parameters to a better estimate?

I have the following graphs:
Figure 1 SNP missingness: For each level of missingness specied on the x axis, the corresponding y-value shows the proportion of SNPs which have missingness less than this.

Figure 2 Missingness per indvididual: For each level of missingness specied on the x axis, the corresponding y-value shows the proportion of individuals which have missingness less than this.

Figure 3 Cumulative frequency of SNPs. For a frequency shown on the x-axis, the corresponding y-value shows the proportion of SNPs with frequency at least this frequency; that is, it shows the proportion of SNPs which will remain if the MAF lter of this x-value is chosen.

Figure 4 HWE distribution. For an HWE-value shown on the x-axis, the corresponding y-value shows the proportion of SNPs with HWE p-value at least this frequency; that is, it shows the proportion of SNPs which will be removed if the HWE lter of this x-value is chosen.

Figure 5 QQ plot for Hardy-Weinberg scores.

Please let me know which one is the best to attach to the question.

Comment: How many SNPs do you have before and after applying those filters? If you’ve ended up removing most of them, then I’d suggest maybe rethinking what values you choose, otherwise I don’t think it necessary. Is there a reason why you thought you should?

Comment: @user438383 I think its due to the graphs that were produced. I dont know how to interpret them and I cannot add them all to the question here. There are 295218 SNPs, 80370 SNPs were left over, too stringent?